# jQuery Image swap from smaller to bigger size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

I'm using jQuery hover effect on an image gallery.  The default size of the images is 265 x 172. They are being displayed horizontally.  I would like it that when a user hover over an image, it swaps it out for another image who's size is 449 x 223.  It needs to look like the image changed subtly and grew in size.

At the moment I have this.  When I hover I can see the default image slide down and the larger image slide up.  I don't want the user to see that transition, instead just the increase in size.

http://jsfiddle.net/g5a2T/8/

jQuery

```
        jQuery('.carousel-img').hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).css('width', '449px');
            jQuery(this).children('.defaultImg').stop().hide("fast"); 
            jQuery(this).children('.largeImg').stop().show("slow");

         }, function() {
             jQuery(this).css('width', '265px');
             jQuery(this).children('.largeImg').stop().hide("fast");
             jQuery(this).children('.defaultImg').stop().show("slow");

        });
```

HTML

```
<ul id="carousel">
    <li class="carousel-img" style="width: 265px;">
        <img class="defaultImg" src="design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block; height: 172px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 265px; opacity: 1;">
        <img class="largeImg" src="design-engine.jpg" style="display: none; height: 223px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 449px; opacity: 1;">
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-img" style="width: 265px;">
        <img class="defaultImg" src="design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block; height: 172px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 265px; opacity: 1;">
        <img class="largeImg" src="design-engine.jpg" style="display: none; height: 223px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 449px; opacity: 1;">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#carousel {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#carousel li {
    float: left;
    height: 223px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    position: relative;
    width: 265px;
}

#carousel li img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: It seems like this might help you: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/hover-zoom-effect-with-jquery-and-css/, that link uses an animate to "zoom" an image and I suspect you can perform the opposite zoom "zoom in" and on callback of the animate you can swap in the new picture that is larger.

Comment: I like this.  The problem is that I need the larger image to start appearing from the top of the smaller image instead of from 0.  So that it looks like the image grew and changed.  Instead of the whole image was hidden an a new one appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<ul id="carousel">
    <li class="carousel-img" style="width: 265px;">
        <img class="defaultImg" src="design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 265px; opacity: 1;" />
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-img" style="width: 265px;">
        <img class="defaultImg" src="design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block;  padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 265px; opacity: 1;" />

    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
#carousel {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#carousel li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 265px;
}

#carousel li img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $('.carousel-img').hover(function () {
        $("img", this).eq(0).animate({
            width: "449"
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $("img", this).eq(0).animate({
            width: "265"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5GEhU/

Comment: This is good.  But, what about an image swap?  It also overlaps the image next to it when it expands.

Comment: If interpret comment accurately, an image "swap" not necessary, can utilize single image , by resizing single image with `css` `width` property; less DOM elements to manipulate, why piece above reduces images to only `defaultImg`. "overlap" could be achieved several ways, by adjusting `css` properties to meet desired "overlap" display. Try http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kwU8K/ Thanks

Comment: The image swap is necessary because its actually a different image that needs to appear.

Comment: Different image or same image with different dimensions ?

Comment: bit.ly/1ilciPQ here's a link

Comment: Not certain what looking at / for ? If possible, describe link. Thanks

Comment: The blue boxes in the middle of the screen - when you hover over them one it expands and the image changes. I would like it to appear as if the image grew in size and changed color instead of fadeIn/fadeOut

Comment: I actually prefer that this link isn't publicized. Can you please delete it?